# how is data stored in a SQL column when it is a single value and 6m rows

Tags: sql-server, memory

I have a sql table, and get table size/row count with the following:

```
SELECT 
    t.name AS TableName,
    s.name AS SchemaName,
    p.rows,
    CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.total_pages) * 8) / 1024.00), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS TotalSpaceMB,
    getdate() as [Time]
into #temp
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN      
    sys.indexes i ON t.object_id = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.object_id AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE 
    t.name NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND i.object_id > 255 
GROUP BY 
    t.name, s.name, p.rows
ORDER BY 
    TotalSpaceMB DESC, t.name

select * from #temp
```

for my table of interest, I get the following info: `6.1m rows`, and `2384.77MB` table size.

my table of interest has one column with a 33character value in all 6.1m rows, I copy this data into a new table and make the necessary change with:

```
select * into  table_of_interest_temp from table_of_interest
update table_of_interest_temp
set Key = 1
where Key = '6cd191449a764432ac3e-ab1c12f900dd'
```

I rerun the memory query above, and my table has is smaller by `6.31MB, to 2378.46MB`.

I would have thought that more memory savings would have taken place, bc when I make changes on another column that has ~2k different keys, a significant reduction is observed.

Can anyone explain why this may be the case?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: reindexing is how space is reclaimed.

The attached SQL may help you to understand (run against a test DB): I took your code and copy/pasta'd about to hopefully provide a rough demo of the concept.

SQL Server stores tables (and anything else in a DB) on 8KB partitions known as a Page. Pages don't have individual fields' data, instead they have row after row (sometimes multiple rows on one page, sometimes not) of data. Because of this, if you have a single variable length field in a table that you reduce the size of the data (not a column change, just an update that means the data happens to use less space than before), SQL will not reclaim any space at all for the update. The page still has the 33 characters per row reserved, it's just not using 32 of those, so for every row in the table you are left with 32 characters of whitespace in the table's storage.

How to reclaim? Reindexing, sort of. The below demo will demonstrate for you that:

- if you have a heap, reduce the field size, and reindex, it may do nothing for you. This is because reindexing heaps just fixes Extent Fragmentation: When extents are out of order (more here, see top reply: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/138878/how-to-lower-heap-fragmentation-in-sql-server ).
- if you have a clustered index, amusingly it'll bloat the index from the update but ultimately reindexing will reduce (my test shows going from 106MB up to 282MB from update and down to 40MB for reindex)
- if you have a heap table, and you want to reclaim space from such an update, ideally you would make a clustered index and then drop it again: Note in my test how table_of_interest2 gets the initial data inserted from the heap of table_of_interest (so it's the same heap basically), then after adding a clustered index the table size is 106MB. Then after the update it bloats up to ~280MB, then reindexing the clustered brought us down to 40MB. Then dropping the clustered (so table_of_interest2 is now a heap) has us again at 40MB (rather than th 122MB that persisted for the heap table alone).

So per these findings, you either need to reindex if you have a clustered index to reclaim that space or build one then drop it to reclaim the space if your table is a heap (alternatively you can export the data to a new table and drop your old one if that works for you).

Code Demo (took about 1m to run on my dev box):

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO
if object_id ('table_of_interest') is not null
    drop table table_of_interest
go
if object_id ('table_of_interest2') is not null
    drop table table_of_interest2
go
if object_id ('tempdb.dbo.#temp') is not null
    drop table #temp
go

CREATE TABLE table_of_interest (val varchar(50));
GO

INSERT INTO table_of_interest (val)
SELECT '6cd191449a764432ac3e-ab1c12f900dd'
GO

INSERT INTO table_of_interest (val)
SELECT val FROM table_of_interest
GO 21 -- exponential, ~1M records

SELECT 'initial population' as tablestate,
    t.name AS TableName,
    s.name AS SchemaName,
    p.rows,
    CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.total_pages) * 8) / 1024.00), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS TotalSpaceMB,
    getdate() as [Time]
into #temp
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN      
    sys.indexes i ON t.object_id = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.object_id AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE 
    t.name NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND i.object_id > 255 
GROUP BY 
    t.name, s.name, p.rows
ORDER BY 
    TotalSpaceMB DESC, t.name

select * from #temp where tablename = 'table_of_interest'
drop table #temp
go
-- before we blast the data, let's make a second table for another test.
SELECT * INTO table_of_interest2 FROM table_of_interest
update table_of_interest SET val = '1'

SELECT 'after update' as tablestate,
    t.name AS TableName,
    s.name AS SchemaName,
    p.rows,
    CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.total_pages) * 8) / 1024.00), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS TotalSpaceMB,
    getdate() as [Time]
into #temp
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN      
    sys.indexes i ON t.object_id = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.object_id AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE 
    t.name NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND i.object_id > 255 
GROUP BY 
    t.name, s.name, p.rows
ORDER BY 
    TotalSpaceMB DESC, t.name

select * from #temp where tablename = 'table_of_interest'
drop table #temp
GO

ALTER INDEX ALL ON [table_of_interest] REBUILD;

SELECT 'after rebuild of heap' as tablestate,
    t.name AS TableName,
    s.name AS SchemaName,
    p.rows,
    CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.total_pages) * 8) / 1024.00), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS TotalSpaceMB,
    getdate() as [Time]
into #temp
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN      
    sys.indexes i ON t.object_id = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.object_id AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE 
    t.name NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND i.object_id > 255 
GROUP BY 
    t.name, s.name, p.rows
ORDER BY 
    TotalSpaceMB DESC, t.name

select * from #temp where tablename = 'table_of_interest'
drop table #temp
go

drop table table_of_interest;
go

-- second test: what if it was a clustered index rather than heap?
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [CIX_table_of_interest2] ON [table_of_interest2] ([val]);
go

SELECT 'with clustered index' as tablestate,
    t.name AS TableName,
    s.name AS SchemaName,
    p.rows,
    CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.total_pages) * 8) / 1024.00), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS TotalSpaceMB,
    getdate() as [Time]
into #temp
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN      
    sys.indexes i ON t.object_id = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.object_id AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE 
    t.name NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND i.object_id > 255 
GROUP BY 
    t.name, s.name, p.rows
ORDER BY 
    TotalSpaceMB DESC, t.name

select * from #temp where tablename = 'table_of_interest2'
drop table #temp
go

update table_of_interest2 set val = '1'
go

SELECT 'after update2' as tablestate,
    t.name AS TableName,
    s.name AS SchemaName,
    p.rows,
    CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.total_pages) * 8) / 1024.00), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS TotalSpaceMB,
    getdate() as [Time]
into #temp
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN      
    sys.indexes i ON t.object_id = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.object_id AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE 
    t.name NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND i.object_id > 255 
GROUP BY 
    t.name, s.name, p.rows
ORDER BY 
    TotalSpaceMB DESC, t.name

select * from #temp where tablename = 'table_of_interest2'
drop table #temp
go

alter index all on [table_of_interest2] rebuild;
go

SELECT 'after rebuild of clustered index' as tablestate,
    t.name AS TableName,
    s.name AS SchemaName,
    p.rows,
    CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.total_pages) * 8) / 1024.00), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS TotalSpaceMB,
    getdate() as [Time]
into #temp
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN      
    sys.indexes i ON t.object_id = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.object_id AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE 
    t.name NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND i.object_id > 255 
GROUP BY 
    t.name, s.name, p.rows
ORDER BY 
    TotalSpaceMB DESC, t.name

select * from #temp where tablename = 'table_of_interest2'
drop table #temp
go

-- now let's go back to being a heap with our reduced data, see how big this heap is starting with the small fields.
DROP INDEX [CIX_table_of_interest2] ON [table_of_interest2];
GO

SELECT 'back to a heap, small data' as tablestate,
    t.name AS TableName,
    s.name AS SchemaName,
    p.rows,
    CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.total_pages) * 8) / 1024.00), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS TotalSpaceMB,
    getdate() as [Time]
into #temp
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN      
    sys.indexes i ON t.object_id = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.object_id AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE 
    t.name NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND i.object_id > 255 
GROUP BY 
    t.name, s.name, p.rows
ORDER BY 
    TotalSpaceMB DESC, t.name

select * from #temp where tablename = 'table_of_interest2'
drop table #temp
go


drop table table_of_interest2;
```